# WordPress footer widget areas not displaying content

Tags: php, wordpress

I have added 3 footer widget areas in [a theme](http://appitfy.com/). I added some content to the widgets but it does not display on the site.

Code in functions.php

```
<?php
/**
 * Register our sidebars and widgetized areas.
 *
 */
function arphabet_widgets_init() {

    register_sidebar( array(
        'name'          => 'Footer sidebar 1',
        'id'            => 'footer_1',
        'before_widget' => '<div>',
        'after_widget'  => '</div>',
        'before_title'  => '<h2 class="rounded">',
        'after_title'   => '</h2>',
    ) );

}
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'arphabet_widgets_init' );
?>
<?php
/**
 * Register our sidebars and widgetized areas.
 *
 */
function arphabet_widgets_init2() {

    register_sidebar( array(
        'name'          => 'Footer sidebar 2',
        'id'            => 'footer_2',
        'before_widget' => '<div>',
        'after_widget'  => '</div>',
        'before_title'  => '<h2 class="rounded">',
        'after_title'   => '</h2>',
    ) );

}
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'arphabet_widgets_init2' );
?>

<?php
/**
 * Register our sidebars and widgetized areas.
 *
 */
function arphabet_widgets_init3() {

    register_sidebar( array(
        'name'          => 'Footer sidebar 3',
        'id'            => 'footer_3',
        'before_widget' => '<div>',
        'after_widget'  => '</div>',
        'before_title'  => '<h2 class="rounded">',
        'after_title'   => '</h2>',
    ) );

}
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'arphabet_widgets_init3' );
?>
```

Code in footer.php:

```
<?php if ( is_active_sidebar( 'arphabet_widgets_init' ) ) : ?>
    <div >
        <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'footer_1' ); ?>
    </div><!-- #primary-sidebar -->
<?php endif; ?>
<?php if ( is_active_sidebar( 'arphabet_widgets_init2' ) ) : ?>
    <div >
        <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'footer_2' ); ?>
    </div><!-- #primary-sidebar -->
<?php endif; ?>
<?php if ( is_active_sidebar( 'arphabet_widgets_init3' ) ) : ?>
    <div >
        <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'footer_3' ); ?>
    </div><!-- #primary-sidebar -->
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: are the `divs` appearing? Try giving one an id and see if it isn the rendered output.

Comment: Try inspect element.

Comment: @ShawnMehan: I added an `id` with the name `test`. It does not show up.

Comment: @DevendraBhandari: What do I do with inspect element?

Comment: to check widget rendering any div

Comment: You are calling get_footer() on the pages you want the footer to appear, right?

Comment: Rather confusingly, all the `dynamic_sidebar()` statements should be `<?php !dynamic_sidebar( 'footer_1' ); ?>` etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fahad uddin
Use this in the footer:

```
<?php if ( is_active_sidebar( 'footer_1' ) ) : ?>
    <div >
        <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'footer_1' ); ?>
    </div><!-- #primary-sidebar -->
<?php endif; ?>
<?php if ( is_active_sidebar( 'footer_2' ) ) : ?>
    <div >
        <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'footer_2' ); ?>
    </div><!-- #primary-sidebar -->
<?php endif; ?>
<?php if ( is_active_sidebar( 'footer_3' ) ) : ?>
    <div >
        <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'footer_3' ); ?>
    </div><!-- #primary-sidebar -->
<?php endif; ?>
```